# How to handle in-app payment checks

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

*Question applies to both Play Store and App Store.*

I have an App developed in Ionic with cordova-plugin-inapppurchase plugin to handle in-app payments.

Everything works but right now I have set it up so every time the App opens, I check the app/play store for the payment status.

In **iOS** (and I am guessing it has to do with my settings) every time the app opens, it asks me for the App Store password. I guess it could be changed in settings, but for the general user it is annoying.

Am I handling it correctly? How often or when should I check for the in-app payment status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer myself:
[Restoring Purchased Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

*Restoring purchases prompts for the user’s App Store credentials, which interrupts the flow of your app: because of this, don’t automatically restore purchases, especially not every time your app is launched.*